# How does acl in security.yml mean in symfony?

Tags: symfony

I have come across this line in security.yml but i do not have any idea what it means..

```
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

WHat does the roles mean and how can i use it in my controller class ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section of the security's configuration aims at restricting paths by roles:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1
```

It basically means: all URLs matching the pattern  `^/_internal` should be only accessible by users with the role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` and from the IP `127.0.0.1`. It secures the route from outside access. The role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` is given to anonymous users as far as the `anonymous` authentication provider is configured in the `firewall` section:

```
firewalls:
    foobar:
        pattern:    ^/foobar
        anonymous:  ~
```